# AFHTTPRequestOperation progress is uneven

Tags: ios, uiprogressview, afnetworking

I use a AFHTTPRequestOperation to upload between 1-6 images to a web server.  The weird thing is that when it reports progress in my "setUploadProgressBlock" it reports totalBytesWritten as:
32,768
32,768
32,768
32,768
3,238
2,420
2,420... and keeps repeating 2420 until final chunk which is the remainder.

I'm using a UIProgressView to report upload progress, which jumps to 30% or so immediately because of the unequal chunks in the beginning (32,768 byte chunks).  I have cheated this to basically ignore the first four large chunks, but I'm wondering if anyone has an explanation for why it does this, or a more elegant way to handle it.  Also, once it reports that all bytes have been written, it sits there "doing nothing" for several seconds which seems like an unreasonably long delay.  I've handled this with a UIActivityIndicator (spinner), but it's annoying that the delay is so long.  I should mention that this is tested on 3g as that will be the target environment.

Answer (score 0):

Can you double check that you're not reading the value for `bytesWritten`, which reports how many bytes were uploaded in the last batch, as opposed to `totalBytesWritten`? Alternatively, it may be that several uploads are being performed simultaneously, which could be confusing if you're logging these all in the same callback.

The "doing nothing" for several seconds could be waiting for the response from the server. Do you have any more details about that?